# React Axios call is not displaying any data even though console.log output shows data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have places in my React Application that makes Axios calls and displays the data just fine.

However, I wanted a for loop, and I found code answer on stackover, but it is 3 years old, so I'm wondering if something changed.

1. I am using webApi in place of Axios  - it is an alias and i'm using elsewhere in the application for the path to server, also the call with `console.log(..` is working displaying an array.
2. I am wondering about the structure of the .get / .then with function(event)  I don't do that in other calls to web api
3. Could there be an issue with the state, or the const in the render() ?  like something occurred already and html table stays blank?

This is my call to retrieve data and console.log shows the data fine.

```
webApi.get(`clinical/offlinemembers/${id}`)
        .then(function(event){
            console.log("event.data", event.data);
            th.setState({
                data: event.data
            });
        });
```

Then in the full code I will paste below,  notice the const `{contents}`  I would love it if this style of code works.

Here is the complete .js code

```
import React from 'react';
import webApi from './api/webApi';
import { withRouter, Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import queryString from 'query-string';
//import ActivateAccount from './ActivateAccount';


function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        console.log(query)//"app=article&act=news_content&aid=160990"
        var vars = query.split("&");
        console.log(vars) //[ 'app=article', 'act=news_content', 'aid=160990' ]
        for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                    console.log(pair)//[ 'app', 'article' ][ 'act', 'news_content' ][ 'aid', '160990' ] 
        if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
         }
         return(false);
}


class MemberOffline extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var th = this;


        const id = getQueryVariable('id');
        console.log("id", id );

        // webApi.get(`clinical/offlinemembers/${id}`)
        //     .then(res => {
        //         console.log("res", res);
        //     });

        webApi.get(`clinical/offlinemembers/${id}`)
            .then(function(event){
                console.log("event.data", event.data);
                th.setState({
                    data: event.data
                });
            });


    }

    render() {
        const contents = this.state.data.forEach(item => {
            //change the title and location key based on your API
            return <tr>
              <td>{item.member_name}</td> 
              <td>{item.member_ID}</td>
              <td>{item}</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
        })
        return(
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div>Case Trakker Dynamo Disconnect | TXAetna</div>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Member Name</th>
                    <th>Member ID</th>
                    <th>DOB</th>
                    <th>Current ILTCM Program Type</th>
                    <th>SAI Status</th>
                </tr>
                {contents}
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default MemberOffline;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

1. No need for `var th = this;`. You can use arrow functions and don't need to recover the context.
2. Can't render objects in react, it'll throw an error. Hence the line `<td>{item}</td`> is not required.
3. `Map` over `forEach`: because we don't need to cause side-effects to our data, map returns a new array altogether. 
   **State mutation is a big no in react.**

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import webApi from './api/webApi';
   import { withRouter, Route, Link, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
   import queryString from 'query-string';
   //import ActivateAccount from './ActivateAccount';


   function getQueryVariable(variable)
   {
           var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
           console.log(query)//"app=article&act=news_content&aid=160990"
           var vars = query.split("&");
           console.log(vars) //[ 'app=article', 'act=news_content', 'aid=160990' ]
           for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                       var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                       console.log(pair)//[ 'app', 'article' ][ 'act', 'news_content' ][ 'aid', '160990' ] 
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
            }
            return(false);
   }


   class MemberOffline extends React.Component {

       constructor(){
           super();
           this.state = {
               data: []
           }
       }

       componentDidMount() {

           const id = getQueryVariable('id');
           console.log("id", id );

           // webApi.get(`clinical/offlinemembers/${id}`)
           //     .then(res => {
           //         console.log("res", res);
           //     });

           webApi.get(`clinical/offlinemembers/${id}`)
               .then((event) => {
                   console.log("event.data", event.data);
                   this.setState({
                       data: event.data
                   });
               });


       }

       render() {
           const contents = this.state.data.map(item => (
               //change the title and location key based on your API
               <tr>
                 <td>{item.member_name}</td> 
                 <td>{item.member_ID}</td>
                 <td></td>
                 <td></td>
               </tr>
           ))
           return(
               <div class="container-fluid">
                   <div>Case Trakker Dynamo Disconnect | TXAetna</div>
                   <table class="table table-bordered">
                   <tr>
                       <th>Member Name</th>
                       <th>Member ID</th>
                       <th>DOB</th>
                       <th>Current ILTCM Program Type</th>
                       <th>SAI Status</th>
                   </tr>
                   {contents}
                   </table>
               </div>
           )
       }
   }


   export default MemberOffline;
   ```

Comment: 1. i had to change item=> ( and closing to {.. }   , but then i got error on `this.setState({`

Comment: Error for that is  `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {member_name, member_ID, member_DOB, programType}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Why did you have to change anything? Also, post the response you are getting from the server.

Comment: because i had to change... arrow function needs brackets not params

Comment: No you didn't have to do anything, the brackets represent a return statement, just use the code I posted and post the response from the server.

Comment: I did paste error from the webpage,  same as F12 dev tools   it wants an array ,  `Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {member_name, member_ID, member_DOB, programType}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Paste the `console.log` of the response you get from webApi.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199708/discussion-between-rohit-kashyap-and-jeremy-miller).